# JavaScript не работает в ИЕ

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Нужна помощь по JavaScript. Нашла скрипт фотогалереи. Именно такой, какой мне нужен. Но вот беда, он не работает в ИЕ, хотя в аннотации сказано, что работает. Но при вставке скрипта в вебстраницу он корректно работает в Опере, Сафари, Хроме, Мозилле. Но не в ИЕ!!! Я совсем нуб в веб-программировании, я понимаю, что что-то нужно подправить в исходном коде, а вот что конкретно... Помогите, а? Вот сам скрипт с примером http://www.03www.ru/2011n4/2011n4-15.html (на фотографии не обращайте внимания, это там такое демо)

Comment: >> JavaScript не работает в ИЕ

Лол, он там и не работал никогда.

Comment: а где там js??? там css один... попробуйте в браузере ActiveX включить...

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-stacked-slideshow.html#url) если кто то хочет посмотреть. Вообще, не имею эксплорера ни в каком виде, поэтому ориентируюсь по гуглу и детским воспоминаниям.
Варианта 3:

1. В ie есть штука ("запрещать все надстройки, кроме"), смысл которой вы наверное сами понимаете.
2. Вы можете проверить что именно не работоспособно: js в ie или сам ie проверив код [Здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zHuqj/)
3. Вы можете оставить свои контакты здесь и помогу по возможности.

Comment: Да, это именно этот скрипт, на него дана ссылка внутри скрипта. Я тоже не поклонник ИЕ, но вроде как обязана заботится и о тех, кто зайдет на мой сайт именно через этот браузер....И я уже поняла, что сама не справлюсь, ибо новичок. Так что с радостью приму любую Вашу помощь. Мой адрес mirrax1@mail.ru

Answer (score 0):

http://www.03www.ru/2011n4/2011n4-15.html - у меня почему-то не заходит на сайт. Насчет javasc., если не кто не ответит то можно сделать проверку браузеров, и для ИЕ выдавать спец. галерею.
**Кстати ИЕ 8-9 тоже не поддерживает Ваш скрипт?**

Comment: Ссылка рабочая, я проверяла еще раз. ИЕ у меня 9-й, на рабочем компе - 8-й, нигде не работает. Надо заметить вот какую деталь: При просмотре примера по вышеприведенной ссылке через ИЕ он работает (хоть немного и топорно)!!! А вот когда вставишь код в свою вебстраницу - работать перестает. Код скопирован и вставлен корректно, что я делаю не так - не могу разобраться :(